# delta functions $e^{x}\delta (x)=\delta (x)$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

How would you prove that;
$$e^{x} \delta (x)= \delta (x)$$

Is it anything to do with the following relationship;
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g'(x)h(x)\,dx =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)h'(x)\,dx.$$

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $\delta(x)$ is a linear functional on some space of suitably nice (in particular, continuous) functions of $\mathbb{R}$. Given a suitably nice function $f$, what does $\delta(x)[f]$ equal?

When you say $e^x \delta(x) = \delta(x)$, what you're saying is that the left hand side and the right hand side act on continuous functions in the same way. Is that true?

Answer (score 5):

Depends on how you define the Dirac delta, if it is defined as a linear functional acting on an $f\in C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R})$:
$$
\delta[f](x) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \delta(x)f(x) \,dx = f(0)
$$
Then we can see for any test function $\phi$:
$$
(e^{x}\delta(\cdot) - \delta(\cdot))[\phi](x) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} (e^x\delta(x)\phi(x) - \delta(x)\phi(x)) \,dx = e^0\phi(0) - \phi(0) = 0
$$
Hence $e^{x} \delta(x) = \delta(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(x)\,dx = f(0).
$$
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\Big(e^x \delta(x)\Big)\,dx = \text{what?}
$$
But look at that last integral this way:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Big(f(x)e^x\Big) \delta(x)\,dx.
$$
This is equal to the value of the function $x\mapsto f(x)e^x$ at $x=0$, because the delta function is defined that way.  Letting $g(x)=e^x\delta(x)$, we now have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(x)\,dx = \int_{\infty}^\infty f(x)g(x)\,dx \text{ for all suitable functions }f.
$$
The definition of generalized functions is such that that implies that $g=\delta$.  ("Suitable" will mean test functions or Schwarz functions or whatever it is you're using in that role in the context in which you're working.)

So be careful to understand the definition.

Answer (score 2):

The $\delta_0$ functional is representable as a measure. You have
$$\delta_0(E) = \cases{1 & if $0 \in E$\cr 0 & otherwise }$$
Then the linear functional here is represented as 
$$f \mapsto f(0) = \int_{R^d} f(\xi)d\delta_0(\xi). $$
It is not hard to show this relation will hold for any continuous function. Your result will follow right away.